# Multiple plus and minus buttons need to use the same function

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 plus and minus buttons on my page. I need all of them to do the same thing once clicked.

html:

```
  <div class="product1">
        <div class="product1-lable"></div>
        <div class="product1-price"></div>
        <button class="minus">+</button>
        <input class="amount" type="amount" value="0"></input>
        <button class="plus">-</button>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
            let btnAdd = document.querySelector('.plus');
            let btnSubtract = document.querySelector('.minus');
            let input = document.querySelector('input');
            btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
            });
            btnSubtract.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
            });
```

Only the first button is working, the other 2 are not.

Comment: You have minus class on your + button

Answer (score 0):

Working fine !

```js
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('.plus');
let btnSubtract = document.querySelector('.minus');
let input = document.querySelector('input');
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
});
btnSubtract.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
});
```

```html
<div class="product1">
  <div class="product1-lable"></div>
  <div class="product1-price"></div>
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  <input class="amount" type="amount" value="0">
  <button class="minus">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So it only works on the first button but not the second one or third

Comment: The first button is A-Okay but the second and third don't click at all. so it seems to me that the function is only being used for the first button?? How do I get it to work for the others?